# How to use Travis without a .travis.yml file in the root folder of a repository?

Tags: travis-ci

I really want to use Travis without the need to store .travis.yml in the root folder of my repository. Any idea if it can be moved in a different folder, stored in another repository or specified on the Travis website?

Comment: As Joe mentioned in his answer, knowing why would probably help us find answers. Your current question may be a victim of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In any case, you could always try another CI service - I remember that Codeship for instance doesn't require any special files in your repo.

Comment: you can have alternatives for Travis CI, check droid.io or other CI servers.

Answer (score 8):

From [Customizing the Build](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/):

> Travis CI uses `.travis.yml` file in the root of your repository to learn about your project and how you want your builds to be executed.

You can't move it, or configure it elsewhere.

> stored in another repository

You could potentially create a boostrap repo that existed only to pull in the real repository during the build. You would lose many (all?) of the benefits of GitHub integration and branch tracking here.

> (Please don't derail this question by asking "why" I may want or need to do that)

Generally, explaining *why* you need something can help people provide more general or creative answers, or help them to understand which constraints you're not aware of.

Comment: That's a fair point and I am aware of (and passionately hate) the XY problem.


The reason I want to remove it from sight will appear shallow to many. My project relies a lot on lowering the mental access barrier to user adoption. I want to user to see the code in the root folder and have the **intuition** that it'll just work, no arbitrary third-party build system or tools in sight, just .cpp code. So the less alien files the best.


It looks like there are solutions for Travis but they aren't worth the trouble. I might give a try to alternative CI products though! Thanks all!

Comment: I agree with this vision, havin a .travis-ci folder for its config seems a simple feature request to accept. Similar for .Github files too.