# Store .travis.yml in .travis folder or elsewhere

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

Instead of using `.travis.yml` in the root of a project, is it possible to store it in a folder called `.travis` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `.travis.yml` represents the only way to configure travis...
Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768540/how-to-use-travis-without-a-travis-yml-file-in-the-root-folder-of-a-repository) question and [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#building-specific-branches) statement